# Using os.system in python to open a new cmd, change its directory and then run some code in the new cmd

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, os.system

I am trying to use os.system from a .py file to open a new cmd, change its directory and then run separate commands in the new cmd. However after changing the directory, the command I enter using '&&' in the o.system runs in the first cmd and not the new one. I know I should use 'subprocess' module in place of 'os' but both have the same limitation. Here is a snippet of a similar code which I personally feel is easy to understand.

os.system('start /wait cmd /k cd C:/Users/FenilD/Desktop/Python/Python 2.7 && echo "hello"')

Here 'hello' prints in the old cmd from where I am running the file which contains the os.system command.

Any ideas how I can get the 'hello' to print in the new cmd?

Comment: The command-line for `cmd /k`  has to be quoted, and `start` should have an explicit window title so it doesn't assume the first quoted string is the title. Use `os.system('start "window title" cmd /k "cd "C:/Users/FenilD/Desktop/Python/Python 2.7" && echo "hello""')`.

Comment: But do you even need to use the CMD shell to do run these commands? It's preferable to run external commands and work with the system directly in Python rather than invoking the shell for this. If you need a new console window, you can do that with the subprocess module via the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flag. The CMD shell itself is not the console, and you don't have to run CMD to get a console. Any console program such as python.exe will inherit or create a console as needed. `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` overrides the default inheritance behavior.